# How to create bookmarklet like pinterest/snatchly that can scrape images

Tags: jquery, image, web-scraping, bookmarklet, pinterest

I am interested to know if anyone can share a link/tutorial about how to create a bookmarklet like pinterest or snatchly that can scrape images.

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Your comment is not helping at all. Most websites' bookmarklet codes are compiled, so it is harder to read. Luckily I found a website that is really helping to get me started: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way/# - thank you very much for your discourage comments.

Comment: Wasn't trying to discourage you. Just giving you facts. If facts discourage you, then I can't help that. I'm glad you are starting with a basic tutorial on bookmarklets. That is the right approach. But that is like the first mile in a marathon. It is very far from being a tutorial on how to create a bookmarklet like pinterest/snatchly. If you are up for the challenge, then I congratulate you. A final note: There is no such thing a a "compiled" bookmarklet. By the time you know enough to succeed at your goal, you'll probably understand this and how to read any bookmarklet.

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarklets normally start with `javascript:` and javascript expression after that. You can test out your javascript code first by running it in Google Chrome Web Inspector and then compress it using some javascript compressing utilities and make an anchor tag with href equal to `javascript:alert("You%20code%20after%20:");`

Make sure you url encode the code before you place it in the anchor tag.

With regards to pulling images you can call this javascript and get all images on the webpage `document.getElementsByTagName('img')`

Comment: Try this out in your browser. In the url bar paste this and hit enter javascript:alert("Hello%20World");

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

I have posted an article describing how to create these sort of bookmarklet in steps.

You can check it here: http://jszen.com/how-to-make-pinterest-like-bookmarklet-pin-it.3.html

Answer (score 0):

To go one baby step beyond Encore PTL's answer, the following script creates a duplicate of the 4th image loaded in the browser on any given page:

```
javascript:var%20e=document.createElement('img');var%20n=document.getElementsByTagName('img')[3].src;e.setAttribute('src',n);document.body.appendChild(e);
```

Note: We have to use '%20' for any spaces.

I'm not sure how to do all the beautiful stuff Pinterest does in their overlay - it looks like their bookmarklet calls to a script:

```
http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='somenumber'
```

Their server sends back a more complicated script that builds the modal window with CSS stored in its 'rules' object. A snipped of the rules:

```
background: transparent; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; width: 100%; border: 0;
```